# How can I delete folder as adminstrator in windows script?

Tags: shell, vbscript

I developed an uninstaller windows script file for my application.
I'm trying to delete a folder from Programfiles (x86) but I'm getting this error

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800A0046' Premission Denied

My code is below.

```
Dim shell, systempath

 set shell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

 systempath = shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%SystemRoot%")

 shell.Run Chr(34) & systempath & "\system32\msiexec.exe" & Chr(34) & "  /x{ProductCode}"

 For Each f In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder("C:\Program Files (x86)\XXXXX").SubFolders
    If LCase(f.Name) <> "dev" Then
        f.Delete
        If Err Then
           WScript.Echo "Error deleting:" & Name & " - " & Err.Description
        Else
           WScript.Echo "Deleted:" & Name
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
 Next
 WScript.Quit
```

The error line is "f.Delete".There is no problem when I ran this code on administrator account.But not an administrator I got the permission denied error.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You probably need to run the uninstaller elevated...

Comment: There is not enough info here to solve you problem. What line is it erroring on? It's clear this is not all the code because you have an error handler in here but are not turning off VBScript error handling with On Error Resume Next.

Comment: Sorry for my incomplete information.The error is "f.Delete".There is no problem when I ran this code on administrator account.But not an administrator I got the permission denied error.How can I work arround for this?